# What terminal configurations affect Vim represent with bare .vimrc?

Tags: vim, terminal, environment-variables, config, alacritty

`vim` in `Terminal.app` (Basic profile) and `Alacritty.app` (no config) feels different.
`.vimrc` content is one statement: `colorscheme blue` (default colo).
Both are launched under `bash` shell without `.bashrc`.
Diff of `env`s:

```
< ALACRITTY_LOG=/var/folders/m6/r1vhznpx5flg71m10r0km5dw0000gp/T/Alacritty-96871.log
< ALACRITTY_SOCKET=/var/folders/m6/r1vhznpx5flg71m10r0km5dw0000gp/T/Alacritty-96871.sock
< COLORTERM=truecolor # unset COLORTERM (not helped)
< COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
10c6
< SHELL=/bin/bash
---
> SHELL=/bin/zsh # Terminal.app var, however use in profile /bin/bash --login [echo $0 -bash] (export SHELL=/bin/bash not helped)
13a10,12
> TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
> TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=440
> TERM_SESSION_ID=6F135ED6-6CD8-4C02-947D-FB0967EEBA1C
19,20c18
< __CFBundleIdentifier=io.alacritty
< __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0x0:0x0
---
> __CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
```

*VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 28 2021 06:52:20) macOS version*

What settings/env.variables/<smth_i_miss> influence on vim presentation (particularly why Alacritty gives mono-color behind the text while Terminal shows weird filling)?
[image]

Comment: There are many. Start by comparing the output of `:echo $TERM` in both Vims. Also `:echo &t_Co`. You can also compare the output of `$ env` in both terminal emulators.

Comment: @romainl both show `$TERM xterm-256color`, `&t_Co 256`. I've added `env`s diff to the question. What do you advise?

Comment: As I have been reading to config neovim, terminal applications inherit the config of the terminal application that invokes it. So your font, background and text colors should be the obvious ones that change. Check alacritty page on [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Alacritty#Colors) to try it out.